# Convert Hebrew .docx to epub (for Kobo)

Tags: epub, conversion, kobo

I have a .docx file of a rough draft of a book in Hebrew that I would like to read on my Kobo.

I have tried the following things:

I tried converting it to epub so that I could read it on my ereader using Calibre, but it fails, without giving an error message that I understand.

I opened the file in LibreOffice, and exported it as a PDF, but this file doesn't display the characters.

I tried changing the font of the document, and exported that as a PDF. This "worked", but because it is a PDF, the letters are very small and it can't be read, practically speaking.

I think I can eventually figure out how to get it working, but if someone has a guide or tried-and-true method, I would be glad to follow their example.

Comment: When you say 'it fails', what do you mean exactly? Does Calibre not produce an epub file at all, or is it just not readable on your Kobo?

Comment: I mean that Calibre fails to produce an epub.

Comment: Hmm. Works for me with some random Hebrew text taken from the internet. Make sure you're using the latest version... maybe try with a smaller sample? Also, as a makeshift, if you use a smaller page size then you should be able to get a more readable PDF.

Comment: Changing the page size is a great tip.